# Search results not scrollable from within slide-out responsive sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in the process of making my first app, a Library type of app through Cordova but for some reason my search's returned results are not scrollable. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? To see the issue just click on the menu option, then click on search, then search up a keyword like "light" and you will see that the results are not scrollable.  Here is the jsfiddle link -->https://jsfiddle.net/oiver55/5m6sapry/1/<--.

Give the search engine sometime to return the results (still trying to figure out why and how to cut down on the search time)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your search result div is in a fixed position there is no height limit.
you have to set the height.
maybe  you should try using flexbox

```
.results-wrapper {
    background-color: burlywood;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 500px;
}
```